# Injecting from many scopes at Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mvp, dagger-2

I want to inject objects from two scopes at the same class.
e-g. I am implementing MVP. As a view I have a fragment. And in those fragment I want to inject:

- presenter from ApplicationScope (I use Singleton)
- derivatives of RecyclerView.Adapter and LayoutManager from ActivityScope.

Is it possible? What are the best practise to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible. There are probably different ways to accomplish that.

It's straightforward as long as each component specifies a scope. For example, if your application-level dependencies are `@Singleton` then your activity-level component also needs a `@Scope` like `@ActivityScope`...

For example: application/singleton scope component:

```
@Singleton
@Component
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    MainPresenter getMainPresenter();
}
```

Activity module:

```
@Module
public class MainModule {
    private final Activity mActivity;

    public MainModule(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideContext() {
        return mActivity;
    }

    // and other activity-specific dependencies here...
}
```

and matching activity-level component:

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = MainModule.class)
public interface MainComponent {
    void initialize(MainActivityFragment mainActivityFragment);
}
```

then it all just works... for example you can inject both the singletons and activity-scope dependencies into the fragment:

```
final MainComponent mainComponent = DaggerMainComponent.builder()
        .applicationComponent(((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent())
        .mainModule(new MainModule(getActivity()))
        .build();

...

mainComponent.initialize(this);
```

See the full working code [here](https://github.com/glombard/so/tree/master/31426863_dagger2_scopes/app/src/main/java/com/codeblast/daggermultiplescopes).

PS. I'm not so sure it's best to make the presenters singletons though :-) For one reason, I'd expect to inject activity-level dependencies into the presenter, but this way it won't be possible... Let me know how this works for you and if you find another approach to retain the presenters.

Comment: ActivityScope is too small, ApplicationScope is too big :( Only `Mortar` can fix this problem in a sophisticated manner, I guess.